# How to use JPA - EntityGraph to load only a subset of entity @Basic attributes?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wildfly, jpa-2.1

I found this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-entitygraphs.htm) about entity-graphs... after read it, it gave me the idea that you can used entity-graphs to retrieve only a subset of `@Basic` fields of a given entity (Until now, I have used entity-graphs to retrieve relationships EAGERLY, i.e, for example, load an Employee[including all its attributes] and its associated Department[including all its attributes])...

So, I decided to try this using a small test:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@NamedEntityGraphs({
    @NamedEntityGraph(
        name = "OnlyName",
        attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "name")
    )
})
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Id
    @Column(name = "code", updatable = false)
    private Long code;

    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Lob @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Column(name = "picture", nullable = false)
    private byte[] picture;

    public Employee() {
       super();
    }
    ...
}
```

Then, to retrieve my entity, I used the following code:

```
    private Employee retrieveFromDatabase(long code) {
        EntityGraph<Employee> graph;                // Material Entity Graph

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        graph = (EntityGraph<Employee>) this.em.createEntityGraph("OnlyName");
        map.put("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", graph);


        return this.em.find(Employee.class, code, map);
    }
```

Now, this code always returns an Employee with all the fields fetched from the database; even the Hibernate logs show a query that selects all employee fields:

`Hibernate: select employee0_.code as code1_0_0_, employee0_.last_name as last_name2_0_0_, employee0_.name as name3_0_0_, employee0_.picture as picture4_0_0_ from employee employee0_ where employee0_.code=?`
)

When I was expecting a query like this: `select employee0_.code as code1_0_0_, mployee0_.name as name3_0_0_ from employee employee0_ where employee0_.code=?`

So, what I'm doing wrong? Does this feature is not [supported](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8776) by Hibernate??

**NOTE:** For the test, I was using hibernate 5.0.10 and wildfly10 ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Actually, you are not doing anything wrong. Yet, you are missing an important piece of information from the [Hibernate ORM User Guide (v5.0.x)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-annotation). In section 2.3.2 we find it:

> `fetch` - FetchType (defaults to `EAGER`)
>
> Defines whether this attribute should be fetched eagerly or lazily. JPA says that EAGER is a requirement to the provider (Hibernate) that the value should be fetched when the owner is fetched, while LAZY is merely a hint that the value be fetched when the attribute is accessed. **Hibernate ignores this setting for basic types** unless you are using bytecode enhancement. See the [BytecodeEnhancement](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#BytecodeEnhancement) for additional information on fetching and on bytecode enhancement.

So: Even though you are giving a query hint to the `em.find(..)` method, it's up to the JPA provider - here: Hibernate - to decide if basic attributes will be fetched eagerly or not. In your case, the `Employee` entity only contains `@Basic` attributes.

For reference, and for a more context as well as a more detailed explanation, see also this [tutorial](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/entity-graph-basic-use.html). It covers differences between `"javax.persistence.fetchgraph"` and `"javax.persistence.loadgraph"`query hints and has example code which demonstrates the above behaviour for the JPA persistence provider Hibernate.

Side notes: I checked..

- .. the Hibernate ORM User Guides [5.1](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-annotation), [5.2](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-annotation), and [5.3](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-annotation): All versions contain the very same statement on the default policy to ignore basic attributes.
- .. the official [JPA 2.1 specification document](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf). On (PDF) page 117, in Section 3.7.4 we find:

  > The persistence provider is permitted to fetch additional entity state **beyond** that specified by a fetch graph or load graph.

The latter quote from the JPA-spec backs the *ORM User Guide* that this it is ok to implement it that way.

*My advice*:

Look into *BytecodeEnhancement* as stated by the Hibernate ORM User Guide (see above).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for you answer ... I hope that in the future, hibernate implements this feature fully ... do you know other jpa implementation that do obey the indicated fetch plan?