# Spring Hibernate: @EntityGraph is ignored

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I want to use the `@EntityGraph` annotation to only load the attributes I need.

```
@Entity
@Data
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String username;
    private String pw;

}

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"username"})
    User readById(long id);

}
```

When I call `userRepository.readByid(1);` I expect him to NOT load the pw attribute, because it is not defined in the `@EntityGraph`, so the SQL should be:

> select
>           user0_.**id** as id1_0_,
>           user0_.**username** as username3_0_ 
>       from
>           user user0_ 
>       where
>           user0_.id=?

but the actuall created SQL by Hibernate is:

> select
>           user0_.**id** as id1_0_,
>           user0_.**pw** as pw2_0_,
>           user0_.**username** as username3_0_ 
>       from
>           user user0_ 
>       where
>           user0_.id=?

Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think here is answered very  same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53490655/how-to-use-jpa-entitygraph-to-load-only-a-subset-of-entity-basic-attributes

Answer (score -2):

We need to define NamedEntityGraph at Entity class i.e User.java. Then refer the entityGraph in repo class. For example

```
    @NamedEntityGraph({
        @NamedEntityGraph(name = "User.loadUsername", attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode("username") })
    }
@Entity
public class User {
```

Then in repo class

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(type = EntityGraphType.LOAD, value = "User.loadUsername")
    User readById(long id);

}
```

You can also refer an example here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph.

Comment: The documentation you linked to has another example immediately following the one you linked to showing that this is not necessary.

Comment: username attribute is of type @Basic. In that example (Example 77. Using AD-HOC entity graph definition on an repository query method) attribute members is of type ManyToMany.

Comment: more details here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53906287/1358551